# How i can delete message after send in telethon?

Tags: asynchronous, telegram, telethon

I send a message to the user via await `client.send_message(entity, message)`
how can i delete this message?

it's not work

```
mes= await client.send_message(entity, message)

client.delete_message(mes.id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
mes = await client.send_message(entity, message)
await mes.delete()
```

Comment: the command deletes both me and the user, how can I make sure that it deletes only me?

Comment: figured out
await client.delete_dialog(user)
thanks